# jQuery AJAX Same Page 404 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm running a simple AJAX call to submit a form:

```
var theform = $('form#id');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: theform.serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    // ...
  }
});
```

The form should submit on the same page we are currently on since there is no specified `url` parameter. Although, I have tried manually inputting `/formpage` and `http://sitename.com/formpage` as the URL, and still get the same results.

In my console view, the only error I'm receiving is a 404 error on the POST request. I'm getting a 404 error when trying to request: `http://sitename.com/formpage` -- which doesn't make sense because I'm on `/formpage` when filling out the form.

Additional data (this is what the error shows in the console):

```
POST http://sitename.com/formpage/ 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:7845

send jquery.js:7845
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7301
(anonymous function) start.js:66      (the script calling the $.ajax function above)
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676
elemData.handle jquery.js:4360
jQuery.event.trigger jquery.js:4594
(anonymous function) jquery.js:5119
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:590
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:237
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:5118
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676
elemData.handle jquery.js:4360
```

Comment: Try specifying a url anyway. `url: ""` or `url: "./"`

Comment: Have you tried putting a URL in?

Comment: Yes, I've tried putting in both: `/formpage` and `http://sitename.com/formpage`

Comment: What happens when you copy/paste this url in a new tab of your browser? Do you see the ajax call in the network tab of the debugger?

Comment: That URL is completely valid. It is the URL that holds the form I am submitting. So it shouldn't show a 404